# Cannot open Python:Select Interpreter nor Jupyter notebooks in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I was using Microsoft VSCode for sometime and then I installed Kite. After installing kite two of my extensions are not working i.e. Python (ms-python.python) and Jupyter (ms-toolsai.jupyter). They are installed but they are not enabled. As you can see in the below image,

[image]

I am not able to enable these extensions as well as shown below
[image].

I tried reinstalling VSCode and anaconda but still I cannot open .ipynb files nor I can select Python interpreter by doing ctrl + shift + p.

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci You mean the extension or the Jupyter notebook itself?

Comment: Try uninstalling Kite and see if you can enable Python and Jupyter back.

Comment: @HélitonMartins Yes I did try but it does not work.

Comment: @Murtaza Basu -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same situation before, the following is my solution, and you could refer to it:

In the folder where VS Code extensions are stored (..:\Users\username.vscode\extensions), find the "`Python`" extension and the "`Jupyter`" extension, and then try to remove or delete them, then reopen VS Code, and install these two extensions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This helped, apparently when you are using it offline I need to take care of the versions of the extension for both Python and Jupyter Notebook